# How to match '0', '00', '000', '0000' ... pattern in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

What statement can I use instead of the below query?

```
Select  *
        From   Customer.dbo.Human
        Where  LTrim(RTrim(Mobile)) In ('0', '00', '000', '0000', ....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to match Mobile numbers that consist entirely of zeroes and spaces and that contain at least one zero.

then the following would be one way..

```
WHERE Mobile LIKE '%0%' AND Mobile NOT LIKE '%[^ 0]%'
```

Comment: These would also match the empty string, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Twinkles - Yes. At the moment. And I doubt that's the desired functionality. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where Len(Mobile) - Len(Replace(Mobile, '0', '')) = Len(Mobile)
```

Comment: Why not `Where Len(Replace(Mobile, '0', '')) = 0` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from Customer.dbo.Human
where CHARINDEX(Mobile, '0') > 0
```

There are a few tricks going on here.  The single '0' happens to be contained in all of your other cases so it works because '0' is contained within '000'

EMPHASIS - This Is a Bad Pattern. It will falsely identify any string with a zero in it.   Any CharIndex Search where the search values is not effectively a primary key or typed property identifier is a dangerous pattern.  i.e If you cant use IN('SpecificValue1','SpecificValue2') then step back an reevaluate.

The solution I would prefer is to not insert values that did not pass a validation, all zero looking strings would be converted to null or empty string on insert or update during a clean up routine.

Comment: Even though the OP accepted this I doubt it will turn out to be what is needed. The pattern seems to be "consists entirely of zeroes" not just "contains a zero"